# Formula for generating the date in every page of specific month in MS Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I wanted to create a simple Scheduling Book for my personal purpose, Each page should have the the Day, Month, Date and Year (e.g. Monday, March 5, 2017).

I manage to do it in a single page by using the Date function in Formula, but I don't know how to increment the page with date of a month.

I've been doing this before in MS Word, but I'm having a hard time to input the date of a month manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Put the first, fixed, date on `Sheet1` on desired cell, such on `A1` `5/29/2017`.
2. Create a new sheet, and put in the same cell this formula:

   `=Sheet1!$A$1 + SHEET() -1`
3. Copy this new sheet to the end of the workbook, and it will keep incrementing without you changing the formula.

**Note:** This formula is dependent on the order of sheets. If you swap the order, the date will **not** be swapped *properly*.

Comment: I'm having a problem in SHEET() , the formula is incorrect.

Comment: SHEET() is for Excel 2013 and newer. Are you using older Excel?

Comment: awww. yes, I'm currently using ms word 2007...